# Angular Template directive for ng-repeat and ng-class

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, templates, directive

iam trying to get the code in a Element Template:

**rent.html**

```
<td>{{ rent.id }}</td>
<td>{{ rent.auto }}</td>
<td>{{ rent.person }}</td>
<td>{{ rent.title }}</td>
<td>{{ rent.start }}</td>
<td>{{ rent.end }}</td>
<td><a ng-href="#" ng-click="acceptRent(rent.id)"><img src="bundles/chriskfzbuchung/images/accept.png" width="15" ng-hide="rent.buchungsStatus == 1"></a></td>
<td><a ng-href="#" ng-click="declineRent(rent.id)"><img src="bundles/chriskfzbuchung/images/decline.png" width="15" ng-hide="rent.buchungsStatus == 2"></a></td>
```

**controller.js**

```
 kfzModule.directive("kfzRent", function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: '/kfz-buchung/rent.html'
        };
    });
```

**overview.html**

```
<tr kfz-rent ng-repeat="rent in rents" ng-class="{'success' : rent.buchungsStatus == 1, 'danger' : rent.buchungsStatus == 2}">
                </tr>
```

I dont know how to deal with the rest in overview.html.

I finally want just an `<kfz-rent></kfz-rent>`.

Thanks!

Comment: I am little confused what do you want ?

Comment: i dont want to have the ng-repeat and the ng-class directive in the overview.html, the overview.html should only be <kfz-rent></kfz-rent>

Comment: put everything from overview.html except kfz-rent attribute into rent.html

Comment: doesnt work with <kfz-rent> element (i did the <tr> in the rent.html)

Comment: i also get no javascript error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
 <kfz-rent ng-repeat="rent in rents" ng-class="{'success' : rent.buchungsStatus == 1, 'danger' : rent.buchungsStatus == 2}">
    <td>{{ rent.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ rent.auto }}</td>
    <td>{{ rent.person }}</td>
    <td>{{ rent.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ rent.start }}</td>
    <td>{{ rent.end }}</td>
    <td><a ng-href="#" ng-click="acceptRent(rent.id)"><img src="bundles/chriskfzbuchung/images/accept.png" width="15" ng-hide="rent.buchungsStatus == 1"></a></td>
    <td><a ng-href="#" ng-click="declineRent(rent.id)"><img src="bundles/chriskfzbuchung/images/decline.png" width="15" ng-hide="rent.buchungsStatus == 2"></a></td>
</kfz-rent>
```

The code for ng-repeat seems to be fine. But you have to create the array in your controller:

```
$scope.rents = [];
```

Dont forget to make a alias for your controller

```
kfzModule.directive("kfzRent", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/kfz-buchung/rent.html'
    };
   },
   controllerAs: 'rentController'
 };
});
```

Cheers,

Valentin